# How to cancel pending request with jQuery in JavaScript Selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium

I have a website with many users clicking 1 button. It appears to make no sense to wait until long-pending ajax request gets response, sometimes more than 1 min. I know how to wait for it, but how to cancel it?

How to cancel all pending requests with jquery.min.js if:

1. Page should NOT be reloaded,
2. nothing disabled on driver

Comment: *to wait until pending jQuery long* – are you talking about a pending ajax request? Add the relevant bits of code, it's hard to help in any way otherwise

Comment: Yes, ajax. I know how to wait all active requests to be finished. I need to know to cancel it as it takes to much time. OR probably I need to know how to wait specific request. something like  Object numberOfAjaxConnections = jsDriver.executeScript("return jQuery.active"); but someone by the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is done by setting a timeout. [With jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it is done like

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...,
    timeout: 10000 // in milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Another thought about this task: 1. Can I use Proxy of switch off pictures to speed up the answer?

Comment: @Oleksandr did my answer helped you with your problem? If it answered your question, accept it by clicking the tick (√) sign. Your new question deserves a separate post (*question*) and you should provide more details: in general, the answer is yes, but it may depend on your case

Comment: Sorry, but no. There is jquery request which can't be stopped. So the question is: a lot of users are clicking (requesting data from DB) in the same time, What should I do to be the first one on response? I was thinking about Proxy closed to server, switching off unnecessary pictures on page

Comment: @Oleksandr that's quite another question. Sounds like you are providing X-Y problems. Could you describe the whole scenario so that we can figure it without switching from one approach to another?

Comment: You are right, after analysis I realized not possible to stop pending request to DB.

Comment: The new task can be new story here. Basically it is looks like this: 
1. I have a website with many users clicking 1 button (sending jquery)
2. Server can answer more less to 20 users in 1 sec.( clicking 1000 users)
3. After clicking to the button it should appear additional web element (time slot) , of cause in case of success on your PC
4. It is not clear how this servers works. What I know: the slots are appearing every day at the same time, there is no any blocks or black lists in case of many clicks from one PC (IP) Pending request is usually take on this time 20-30 sec, 1/10 passed.

Comment: Target is: to be the first, until all slots is not gone. 
PS: how to wait for element and click, I know, also have a code how to wait ajax requests.

Comment: @Oleksandr this really deserves a new question, it's much more convenient to see an edited question than read a growing number of comments and compile those into a picture in one's head. For now, I didn't get: "to be the first" – to do/get what?